# Structured Streaming - Joining 2 DataFrames from the same Streaming source

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, window, watermark, spark-structured-streaming

I have this Spark app that takes in a Twitter stream.

I added a time column:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
timestamp_df = tmp_df2.withColumn('time', unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
```

Collect the fields that I need that doesn't require flattening:

```
main_df = (
    timestamp_df.selectExpr(['time', 'created_at', 'id',...])
)
```

I flatten the other parts and convert the list of strings to a string:

```
entities_df = (
    timestamp_df
    .select(['time', 'id', explode('entities.user_mentions').alias('temp')])
    .selectExpr(['time', 'id AS tmp_id', 'temp.screen_name'])
    .withWatermark('time', '10 seconds')
    .groupBy(
        'tmp_id', window('time', '10 seconds', '5 seconds')
    )
    .agg(collect_set('screen_name').alias('tmp_screen_name'))
    .withColumn('entities_user_mentions_screen_name', concat_ws(', ', 'tmp_screen_name'))
)
```

And then join these 2 DataFrames together to get the data that I needed:

```
final_df = (
    main_df
    .join(entities_df, main_df.id == entities_df.tmp_id)
    .select(['created_at', 'id', ...])
)
```

I get back empty DataFrames when this runs.

When I ran the codes on static data using these codes:

```
entities_df = (
    timestamp_df
    .select(['time', 'id', explode('entities.user_mentions').alias('temp')])
    .selectExpr(['time', 'id AS tmp_id', 'temp.screen_name'])
    .groupBy('tmp_id')
    .agg(collect_set('screen_name').alias('tmp_screen_name'))
    .withColumn('entities_user_mentions_screen_name', concat_ws(', ', 'tmp_screen_name'))
)
```

If I run the above (without the watermark) I get this error:

> Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on > streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you disproved me?

Comment: I think so. I got this up and working and saving to a database.

Comment: Misinterpreted, you appear correct.

Comment: Somehow I cannot get this to work, all sort so errors. Can you post the complete source in your answer or send as I am keen to see why I cannot get it. Not sure I would need it if I look at most use cases,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved the issue. Just a few changes to the code:

```
timestamp_df = tmp_df2.withColumn('time', current_timestamp())
```

instead of:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
timestamp_df = tmp_df2.withColumn('time', unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
```

For this I don't think it would make a difference but I didn't try.

And for the entities_df:

```
entities_df = (
    timestamp_df
    .select(['time', 'id', explode('entities.user_mentions').alias('temp')])
    .selectExpr(['time', 'id AS tmp_id', 'temp.screen_name'])
    .withWatermark('time', '5 seconds')
    .groupBy(
        'tmp_id',
        window('time', '5 seconds')
    )
    .agg(collect_set('screen_name').alias('tmp_screen_names'))
    .withColumn('entities_user_mentions_screen_names', concat_ws(', ', 'tmp_screen_names'))
)
```

Comment: What is the moral of the story firstly?